# Does Spark support insert overwrite static partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, shark-sql, apache-spark-sql

I noticed in the current Spark Sql manual that inserting into a dynamic partition is not supported:

> Major Hive Features
>
> Spark SQL does not currently support inserting to tables using dynamic partitioning.

However, is insert/overwriting into static partitions supported?

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL does not currently support inserting to tables using dynamic partitioning as of version spark 1.1

Static is supported, you need to write data in hive table location.

Comment: So an existing Hive query using 'insert overwrite table tablename partion...' would work, right? Sorry don't yet have an environment setup to test.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-2-0.html), Spark 1.2.0 supports dynamically partitioned inserts.  Refer to [SPARK-3007](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3007).